# count operations grouped by country, return dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Data:

| country | operations |
| --- | --- |
| India | A |
| Malaysia | B |
| Croatia | C |
| India | C |
| India | C |
| Malaysia | D |
| Malaysia | A |

Desired Output:

`{ "India" :{"A":1,"C":2},"Malaysia":{"B":1,"A":1,"D":1},"Croatia":{"C":1}}`

I have tried :

```py
arrays = [countrylist, opslist]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('Country', 'Ops'))

df=pd.DataFrame(index)

count = list(df[0].value_counts())

clist = list(df[0].unique())

csdict = dict()

for country,service in clist: 

csdict.setdefault(country, []).append(service) 

country_list = list(csdict.keys())

service_list = list(csdict.values())

fdict = { "country" : country_list, "services" : service_list}

dataf = pd.DataFrame(fdict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary comprehension with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) per groups:

```
d = {k: v.value_counts(sort=False).to_dict() 
         for k, v in df.groupby('country', sort=False)['operations']}

print (d)
{'India': {'A': 1, 'C': 2}, 'Malaysia': {'B': 1, 'A': 1, 'D': 1}, 'Croatia': {'C': 1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) method:

```
z = list(zip(df.country, df.operations))

output = dict()
for c, o in z:
    output[c] = output.get(c) or dict()
    output[c][o] = z.count((c, o))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'India': {'A': 1, 'C': 2}, 'Malaysia': {'B': 1, 'D': 1, 'A': 1}, 'Croatia': {'C': 1}}
```